# Purpose of fs.hdfs.hadoopconf in flink-conf.yaml

Tags: apache-flink

Newbie to Flink. 
I am able to run the example wordcount.jar on a file present in remote hdfs cluster without declaring fs.hdfs.hadoopconf variable in flink conf.

So wondering what exactly is the purpose of above mentioned variable.
Does declaring it changes the way one runs the example jar ?

Command :

```
flink-cluster.vm ~]$ /opt/flink/bin/flink run  /opt/flink/examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/tmp/test-events
```

Output:

```
.......
07/13/2016 00:50:13 Job execution switched to status FINISHED.
(foo,1)
.....
(bar,1)
(one,1)
```

Setup :

- Remote HDFS cluster on hdfs://hadoop-master.vm:9000
- Flink cluster on running on flink-cluster.vm

Thanks

**Update** : 
 
As pointed out by Serhiy, declared fs.hdfs.hadoopconf in conf but on running the job with updated argument `hdfs:///tmp/test-events.1468374669125` got the following error

flink-conf.yaml

```
# You can also directly specify the paths to hdfs-default.xml and hdfs-site.xml
# via keys 'fs.hdfs.hdfsdefault' and 'fs.hdfs.hdfssite'.
#
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/
fs.hdfs.hdfsdefault :  hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/
```

Command :

```
flink-cluster.vm ~]$ /opt/flink/bin/flink run  /opt/flink/examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input hdfs:///tmp/test-events
```

Output :

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Creating the input splits caused an error: The given HDFS file URI (hdfs:///tmp/test-events.1468374669125) did not describe the HDFS NameNode. The attempt to use a default HDFS configuration, as specified in the 'fs.hdfs.hdfsdefault' or 'fs.hdfs.hdfssite' config parameter failed due to the following problem: Either no default file system was registered, or the provided configuration contains no valid authority component (fs.default.name or fs.defaultFS) describing the (hdfs namenode) host and port.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.attachJobGraph(ExecutionGraph.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1026)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html):

> `fs.hdfs.hadoopconf`: The absolute path to the Hadoop File System’s
>   (HDFS) configuration directory (**OPTIONAL VALUE**). Specifying this value
>   allows programs to reference HDFS files using short URIs
>   (`hdfs:///path/to/files`, without including the address and port of the
>   NameNode in the file URI). Without this option, HDFS files can be
>   accessed, but require fully qualified URIs like
>   `hdfs://address:port/path/to/files`. This option also causes file
>   writers to pick up the HDFS’s default values for block sizes and
>   replication factors. Flink will look for the “core-site.xml” and
>   “hdfs-site.xml” files in the specified directory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply , even i was thinking on same lines but declaring the variable and using the updated command line argument throws up error. Please check the updated section in original question . Thanks

Comment: @coredump fs.hdfs.hadoopconf should be pointing to the directory which contains hadoop configuration (the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml) and not to the url of the namenode :). The node which is executing the job should have those files defined somewhere, otherwise it has no information about remote cluster endpoints.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense ,  as i am running jobs on a stand alone flink cluster with a stand alone HDFS cluster ( No Yarn ). So the value for the variable should be `/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/` . Any idea where exactly should namenode be declared ? I don't see anyplace within flink conf directory. Thanks once again.

Comment: @coredump Generally Hadoop configuration is placed into `/etc/hadoop/conf` (on the cluster where Hadoop is installed). The namenode configuration is generally placed into `hdfs-site.xml`. If you do not have hdfs-site.xml in the machine which is submitting the jobs, you should copy the file to that machine and point the `fs.hdfs.hadoopconf` to it.